# Convert date format in mysql 8 [ string d/m/y TO date ]

Tags: php, mysql, csv, date, regexp-replace

I'm inserting csv file through php into database
what I did is I've created two tables
first table contain the whole csv file
the second table contain the filtered csv file

where the first table contain 84 columns
and the second table contain 9 columns

I have in the csv file dates in the format d/m/y
example : 24/06/20

so in the first table I insert everything as string
then I created a mysql request to insert from table one to table two
and I change the format d/m/y string TO date

I used different function to convert string into date but all of them reads the date from right to left so I end up with a result such as

table one 24/06/20  insert into table two convert into date
result 20-06-2024

after searching for different solution I ended up using REGEXP_REPLACE() to reverse the order of the string from LTR -> to -> RTL
then I convert it using STR_TO_DATE()

```
"INSERT INTO tableTwo (date) select 
        STR_TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(date,'^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$','\\\\3-\\\\2-\\\\1') , '%Y-%m-%d') AS mydate FROM tableOne"
```

This solution worked but I had to use MariaDB.

how to get the same result using Mysql 8.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not clear on the problem here str_to_date will convert a date in the format d/m/y to a valid mysql date (ie yyyy-mm-dd) without issue-  str_to_date(<coltoconvert>,'%d/%m/%y')

Comment: Also you can convert it using php without using any mysql functions

Comment: @P.Salmon it does work indeed, I don't get it I've been trying to do that many time but the result was inverted thanks your help

Comment: @MustafaHamdi well I'm using php to convert it as well for the display